# F5 Load Balancer appending <script> to JSON Ajax Responses

Tags: javascript, json, load-balancing, f5

I am having an issue where the client's F5 load balancer is adding Javascript (.....) tags to the end of each AJAX request. This happens for all AJAX requests, the ones in concern are JSON objects.

The problem is that when these tags are appended to the JSON in the response, there are issues because this is no longer valid JSON. It seems a bit unusual that I should have to alter all responses to application/text and remove all script tags before parsing to JSON.

This only occurs when performance monitoring is enabled.

Has anyone experienced this issue or can anyone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 1):

best site to answer questions related to F5 technologies is https://devcentral.f5.com/